# Converting circular structure to JSON in middleware callback

Tags: node.js, express

I am having issue in middleware for authentication users token it says Converting circular structure to JSON Converting circular structure to JSON
at stringify (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js), if the authorization is successful I redirected it to my callback url, my callback url is like this. `"https://www.myapp.com/callback"`

This is the code for middleware

```
callback(s, f){

    router.get("/callback", (req, res, next) => {
        const code = req.query.code;
        const state = req.query.state;
        const friendship_status_changed = req.query.friendship_status_changed;
        if (!code){
            debug("Authorization failed.");
            return f(new Error("Authorization failed."));
        }
        if (req.session.line_login_state !== state){
            debug("Authorization failed. State does not match.");
            return f(new Error("Authorization failed. State does not match."));
        }
        debug("Authorization succeeded.");

        this.issue_access_token(code).then((token_response) => {
            if (this.verify_id_token && token_response.id_token){
                let decoded_id_token;
                try {
                    decoded_id_token = jwt.verify(
                        token_response.id_token,
                        this.channel_secret,
                        {
                            audience: this.channel_id,
                            issuer: "https://access.line.me",
                            algorithms: ["HS256"]
                        }
                    );
                    debug("id token verification succeeded.");
                    token_response.id_token = decoded_id_token;

                    console.log(token_response.id_token);
                } catch(exception) {
                    debug("id token verification failed.");
                    if (f) return f(req, res, next, new Error("Verification of id token failed."));
                    throw new Error("Verification of id token failed.");
                }
            }
            s(req, res, next, token_response);
        }).catch((error) => {
            debug(error);
            if (f) return f(req, res, next, error);
            throw error;
        });
    });
    return router;
}
```

and in my server.js this is how I call it using app.use

```
app.use("/callback", login.callback((req, res, next, token_response) => {
    // Success callback
  res.json(token_response);
},(req, res, next, error) => {
    // Failure callback
    res.send(req);
  //res.status(400).json(error);

}));
```

These are my dependencies and devdepencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "circular-json": "^0.5.1",
    "debug": "^3.1.0",
    "ejs": "^2.5.6",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.1",
    "line-login": "^1.0.8",
    "node-fetch": "^1.7.3",
    "nodemon": "^1.14.11",
    "serve-static": "^1.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "request": "^2.83.0",
    "tape": "^4.7.0"
  },
```

Comment: Well, you can't turn an object into JSON that has a circular reference in it.  JSON does not support that in the format or in any of the stringify or parse functions. What do you expect to do there?  You need to understand where the circular reference is coming from an build a new object that has just your data and no circular references in it.

Comment: I just want to the user to redirect to callback url after successful authorization. however it throws an error like that

Comment: Why do you think `token_response` is passed to your middleware?  That is not a standard middleware parameter.  That seems to me to be your problem.  You're trying to do `res.json(token_respone)` of something else that is not your token.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on how to do it better?

Comment: `app.use()` middleware must get all it's state from the `req` and `res` objects.  I don't know what your `f()` and `s()` things are doing.  Never seen that.  Can't imagine it's right, but you don't show the larger context to even understand what it is.

Comment: s and f are success and failure callbacks they are function serves as a parameter

Comment: I give up.  Don't understand what you're trying to do at all.  Doesn't look like any express code or middleware code or auth code I've ever seen.